# How to share files between php projects in visual studio?

Tags: php, windows, visual-studio

I am using `php tools` installed in `visual studio`.

I have a solution containing two projects for different hosts, "index.php" in both projects should have the same code, so when I change it in one project, I reflect changes in other project too. I want to remove "index.php" from second project and add a reference to "index.php" from first project.

Adding "Existing Item" to second project from first project, copies files in second project folder, so is not useful for my case.

Comment: You can't do it in the same way as you can in .NET, since PHP doesn't compile the code but uses the actual source files at run time. Any server running your code needs the actual files in place. You could put that file in it's own repo and then load it through composer in your projects?

Comment: I am not using any kind of version control.

Comment: You can (and probably should) start doing that, though? It will help you backup your code _and_ it can help you with your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fast solution**

1) Create a symlink for index.php from first project to second project.

For linux `ln -s project1/inex.php project2/inex.php`

For windows `mklink project1/inex.php project2/inex.php`

Hence all changes made on index.php from first project will automatically reflect in second project.

**Elegant solution**

1) Create a PHP file having common code(like a library).

2) Include that in both project's `index.php`

This method will be helpful if you want to add some code exclusively for one project in the future.

Comment: hard links in windows solved my problem. Second solution does not apply for my case: if I include a file out of project, the file won't copy to server when I publish my project.